# Convert encoding before download

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I'm searching a method to convert a torrent encoding (from UTF-8-BOM to WINDOWS-1252) before download because if I download it simply with readfile() the torrent is not valid bencoding, so I need to convert it to WINDOWS-1252 or CP1252.

Click Download on my page, and download the torrent file encoded in WINDOWS-1252.

This is my script:

`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$tname.torrent\"");`
`header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");`
`header("Content-Length: " . filesize($fn));`
`$content = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1252", readfile($fn));`
`print($content);`

Acually, this script is not working because when I download the file, it's empty.
What to do?

Comment: Why would one want to do that? Why encoding to a past world? We are happy that most systems more or less offer unicode these days. Enjoy it! Apart from that: are you sure that the content of the file can actually be encoded in such an old 8 bit encoding? I mean there is a reason for unicode: it allows to use characters you cannot describe in an 8 bit encoding. That might actually be the reason why your `iconv()` call fails...

Comment: I need the encoding because: when I upload the torrent (upload.php form), the torrent is correctly uploaded and it's working - if I download it through ftp - but when I download it through download.php, torrent is not valid bencoding. I'm trying to make a torrent platform and I need that... If you can explain to me what to do...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with a solution if I do not understand the issue. If the torrent is working fine, then why re-encode it? To what purpose? Wouldn't it make more sense to find out why the file cannot be used ("is not valid") after that download? What is wrong with it? How do the two versions of the file differ between the uploaded and the downloaded version?

Comment: Look. A torrent is encoded in ANSI (Notepad++). I have GTA V torrent, if I open it with notepad++ I see it's encoded in ANSI. When I download my torrent from my own website, when I open it with Notepad++, I see it's encoded in UTF-8-BOM, and if I change it's encoding to ANSI, it's working again.

Comment: That's why I need to re-encode the file on download. When the torrent is downloaded, it's encoded in UTF-8-BOM. I need when I download it, the file to be encoded in ANSI, not UTF-8-BOM.

Answer (score 0):

`readfile` prints the requested file directly, but you're using it like it would return the file's contents.
For that you'll have to use `file_get_contents`.

You might also get the wrong file size, because a file encoded in UTF-8 might very well have a different size than one encoded in Windows-1252.
So instead of `filesize($fn)`, use `strlen($content)`.

Comment: When I do that, the file is empty. I mean, it doesn't convert nothing.

Comment: @Lego_Infinity And the file itself is readable by the PHP process, is non-empty and is UTF-8 encoded? What does `filesize($fn)` return?

Comment: Yes. The file is readable by the PHP. The file is not encoded in UTF-8, it's in ANSI, but when I download it I receive the UTF-8 version.

Comment: @Lego_Infinity You mean ASCII? Also, both UTF-8 and Windows-1252 contain the ASCII charset, so converting an ASCII file from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 should do exactly nothing.

Comment: So, how I have to do? If I view the torrent with readfile from PHP script it's not exactly like I view the file in Notepad++.

Comment: @Lego_Infinity What's the difference then? And do they have different checksums?

Comment: I don't know how to view the checksums, but uTorrent can't read the torrent in UTF-8-BOM, just in ANSI.

Comment: @Lego_Infinity You'd have to take the md5 or sha1 hash of the entire file, and compare it to the one of the other file. But BOM is a whole new story. Because that's not an encoding, but actual characters at the beginning of a file. And you say your local file doesn't have it, but the downloaded one does? If so, what does `echo base64_encode(substr(file_get_contents($fn), 0, 3));` on your server yield?

Comment: Yes. The file is encoded in ANSI, but the downloaded file is UTF-8-BOM. base64_encode makes the file to be empty when I download it.

Comment: Don't download the base64 thing, just print it (on a different page maybe).

Comment: Ok, so the file does not have a BOM... are you including any PHP files, and could one of those have a BOM?